# Can I use React-Intl's Built-In Names for Time Periods in my App?

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

Say I have a component such as this:

```
<FormattedMessage
    id='ui.widget.cycleOffsetSelector.timeCycle.label'
    defaultMessage="This {cycle}"
    values={{cycle: props.cycle}}
/>
```

Because the `props.cycle` in my example is actually a time-period like `day`, `week`, `month`, etc, I need to translate that text too before passing it in the FormattedMessage. What is the correct way to do this kind of *translation within a translation*?

Best I can come up with this:

```
const intlPeriod = {
  day: intl.formatMessage({id: 'timePeriod.week', defaultMessage: 'day'}),
  week: intl.formatMessage({id: 'timePeriod.week', defaultMessage: 'week'}),
  month: intl.formatMessage({id: 'timePeriod.month', defaultMessage: 'month'}),
};

<FormattedMessage
    id='ui.widget.cycleOffsetSelector.timeCycle.label'
    defaultMessage="This {cycle}"
    values={{cycle: intlPeriod[cycle]}}
/>
```

Is this the only way?

I see that within the node-js package for `react-intl`, in the `lib\locale-data\[lang].js` file, there are already values defined for `day`, `week`, `month`, etc. Is there a way to access/use those strings in my app directly?

I'm using the `v2` branch of `react-intl`.

Answer (score 1):

The `ui.widget.cycleOffsetSelector.timeCycle.label` message should be something like this:

```
en-US

This {cycle, select,
    day {day}
    week {week}
    month {month}
}

es-US

{cycle, select,
    day {Este día}
    week {Esta semana}
    month {Este mes}
}
```

This allows for the Spanish version to correctly switch between the masculine and feminine Este/Etsa depending on the value of `cycle`.